# Aspect ratio full screen image

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I display an image that fills the whole screen (HTML or Javascript) but doesn't stretch and get all distorted, it keeps aspect ratio.

So it will be centered and either:

Have 100% height and x% width (where "x" is less than or equal to 100%)

or

Have y% height and 100% width (where "y" is less than or equal to 100%)

For something like a full screen image viewer web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {  
    height: 100%;
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set one of width or height and other will be set automatically according to image sides ratio.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.img-class {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

You can set container div to be exactly positioned on the screen by using position absolute, if needed.